# DOJO creating google spreadsheet

Tags: dojo, google-sheets-api

Is there any way, short of routing through a server, to create and update a Google spreadsheet in pure javascript.

It looks like JSONP would be the way to do it, but I do not think that is implemented on Googles part.

Is there another way?

I would like to have a pure HTML5 app, preferably with no server running.

Answer (score 0):

There is gdata api from google: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/, there is also sample, which describes how to go around with cross site restrictions https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Spreadsheet api https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/.